# The type or namespace name could not be found keyedcollection

Tags: c#, keyedcollection

I'm fairly new to C# so forgive me if this is a stupid question. I'm experiencing an error but I do not know how to resolve it. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

This code line

```
public class GClass1 : KeyedCollection<string, GClass2>
```

Gives me the error

```
'GClass1' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string,GClass2>.GetKeyForItem(GClass2)'
```

From what I've read this can be resolved by implementing the abstract member in the inherited class like so

```
public class GClass1 : KeyedCollection<string, GClass2>
{
  public override TKey GetKeyForItem(TItem item);
  protected override void InsertItem(int index, TItem item)
  {
    TKey keyForItem = this.GetKeyForItem(item);
    if (keyForItem != null)
    {
        this.AddKey(keyForItem, item);
    }
    base.InsertItem(index, item);
}
```

However this gives me errors saying 'The type or namespace name could not be found TKey/TItem could not be found.'

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TKey` and `TItem` are the type parameters of `KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>`.

Since you're inheriting from `KeyedCollection<string, GClass2>` with the concrete types `string` and `GClass2` respectively, you're supposed to replace the placeholder types `TKey` and `TItem` in your implementation with those two types:

```
public class GClass1 : KeyedCollection<string, GClass2>
{
  public override string GetKeyForItem(GClass2 item);
  protected override void InsertItem(int index, GClass2 item)
  {
    string keyForItem = this.GetKeyForItem(item);
    if (keyForItem != null)
    {
        this.AddKey(keyForItem, item);
    }
    base.InsertItem(index, item);
}
```

Comment: That works great. However another error has popped up. This time its related to the previous "fix". I forgot that GetKeyForItem is protected. The new error tells me that I can't change access modifiers when overriding System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string,GClass2>.GetKeyForItem(GClass2)

Comment: Change it back. You should probably also implement `GetKeyForItem()` - I just realized there isn't any implementation (taking from your example code)...